# Multiple-entry Schengen visa for Indian citizens having UK visitor visa

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

My family and I already have a UK visitor visa and confirmed return tickets back to India.

I want to apply for Schengen visas for our entire party. We want to travel through the Schengen area various times during our stay in the UK with my sister's family (she is a British citizen.)

We would need multiple-entry visas as we plan to visit various Schengen areas during the weekends. I am confused about how to apply. Will it be sufficient to show 5 to 7 days hotel booking in France and a return ticket to India for the multiple entries while asking for around 30 days for the Schengen visa. We are staying in the UK for 10 weeks total.

Comment: Note that double-entry visa are specifically intended for a single trip between the UK and the Schengen area in the middle of a Europe trip. Depending on your situation, a multiple-entry visa might be a little harder to get but as toy explained it's largely up to the consulate.

Comment: I am trying the same for my Mom.
Sachin - did it work out for you?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to go back and fourth between the UK and Schengen area? As many might have told you already the decision really depends on the embassy so no one can guarantee whether you will get a multiple entry visa or just single visa. This largely depends on your supporting documents.

I can tell you from my past experience. I applied for a Schengen visa with French embassy for 5 days. I showed all the hotel booking and return tickets with enough money to cover the whole trip. But in the document I requested multiple entry for 6 months. I usually got it as I requested. I asked the embassy directly you can write in the form as many days as you want, maximum is 1 year. But the decision is still with the embassy.

You mentioned that you will be staying in the UK for 10 weeks that means your UK visa isn't valid more than 3 months so when you apply for Schengen visa you need to show your return ticket to your home country as well. They usually request that when they examine the documents at the embassy.

Comment: (+1) Were you a UK resident when you applied for your French Schengen visa?

Comment: Yes I was a UK resident. Sorry I should have mentioned that. but my friend did the same thing on 1 year student visa and got 6 month multiple entry as well.